# Is there a way to return early from a select statement in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I take a user-provided search query and split it into tokens, then generate a `WHERE` clause that checks each token against each text column (I'll leave out the indexes here for brevity, but they are well-indexed for with gin trigrams and performance is generally good).

Given a table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.people (
    first_name text NOT NULL,
    last_name text NOT NULL,
  full_address text NOT NULL
)
```

and a search query such as `'barry wisteria lane'`, I'll end up with a `SELECT` statement similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM public.people WHERE
  (
    first_name ILIKE '%barry%' OR
    last_name ILIKE '%barry%' OR
    full_address ILIKE '%barry%'
  ) AND (
    first_name ILIKE '%wisteria%' OR
    last_name ILIKE '%wisteria%' OR
    full_address ILIKE '%wisteria%'
  ) AND (
    first_name ILIKE '%lane%' OR
    last_name ILIKE '%lane%' OR
    full_address ILIKE '%lane%'
  )
  LIMIT 10
  -- this order by is psuedocode that hopefully expresses what's happening
  -- an actual example would be very long and difficult to read
  -- the result is rows that are matched due to hits on first_name are first
  ORDER BY similarity_to_tokens(first_name), similarity_to_tokens(last_name), similarity_to_tokens(full_address) DESC
```

this is fine and very performant. It becomes unperformant if the search query is short and returns a lot of matching rows which then need to be sorted. Sorting all these rows is a waste if there are more rows that matched on `first_name` than the `LIMIT`, because the other rows will always be discarded after the sort.

It's probable that I'm thinking about this problem from the wrong angle because I'm new to database work, but what seems like a simple way of gaining performance (in a normal programming language) would be to stop checking for matches on `last_name` and `full_address` if the number of matches on `first_name` has already reached what's specified in `LIMIT`, seeing as when the rows are sorted, those that matched on first_name are first.

It seems to me that setting and modifying variables is not possible in SQL, so is there another way to approach this?

Currently I do it in the application layer, where I decide if I feel the query is so short it warrants a first attempt where I only check `first_name`, then do a second call to the database if too few results are returned from the first attempt. But making 2 calls for one query is ugly and makes the performance worse in the case of misses with the initial call.

Comment: I guess ugly is in the eye of the beholder.  If the first-executed query returns too few rows, it would probably be pretty quick about doing it, so little harm done (and any data it had to read from disk will probably be needed immediately by the next query).  If you have long network latency between the app server and database server, fix it: it will cause more trouble than just this.

Comment: The server and application are running on the same machine, and yes you are correct - the first call happens pretty quickly. Maybe I'm just being greedy about those 40 milliseconds it might take..